# checking if svg element is inside the viewbox

Tags: javascript, svg, viewbox

having a SVG inline an HTML document ,
with a viewbox "x y w h".
How can I check if an element is inside the view box?

by saying element it could be a nested child path inside a group and so on ...

so I think I'm looking for a build in function of SVG ,or a quick fast why to check it.

I've tried saving the viewbox cords ,and the element I want to check if it's inside the viewbox
I did something like :

```
while (parent ! the svg element ...)
{
   parent = get elem parent 
}
```

// now I have the most top parent of this element ,inside the svg doc
now check if parent inside viewbox , if true then child also , otherwise false

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try the [checkEnclosure](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__checkEnclosure) method of SVGSVGElement.

Comment: Could you give us an example on how to do it?

Comment: @Norfeldt  Do you mean [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) ?

Comment: I meant a code example on how to use checkEnclosure - I can't figure out how to do it. I'm animating some text in and out of the viewport and would like to test if it is inside of it.